# Property cannot be found in forward class object

Tags: ios, xml, properties, gdataxml

I'm adapting [This tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/725/how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml) to my app, and I've got it boiled down to one last error, which is stopping me in my tracks. The program is unable to find a property in another file, but that property is clearly defined. Here is the code in question:

The actual error line:

```
for (DTContact *dtc in _dtContact.contact) {
```

the .h for the file, and items in question:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class XMLTestViewController;
@class DTCXMLResponse;

@interface XMLTestController : UIViewController{
    UIWindow *window;
    XMLTestViewController *viewController;
    DTCXMLResponse *_dtContact;
}


@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet XMLTestViewController *viewController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) DTCXMLResponse *dtContact;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *mybutton;
-(IBAction)buttonClicked;

@end
```

It's having issues with the _dtContact.contact. It can't find the contact in the file DTCXMLResponse. Here is the .h file and the section of the .m:

.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface DTContactXMLResponse : NSObject {
    NSMutableArray *_contact;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *contact;

@end
```

.m

```
#import "DTCXMLResponse.h"

@implementation DTContactXMLResponse
@synthesize contact = _contact;

- (id)init {

    if ((self = [super init])) {
        self.contact = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;

}

@end
```

So theres that. As you can see, I have 'contact' propertied in the DTCXMLResponse.h, and linked in the .m.

Answer (score 195, accepted):

This error usually points out that Xcode can not recognize your symbol.
I can assume this is DTContact.

Try to insert this in your .h file:

```
#import DTContact.h
```

Comment: it's finding the file, just not the property. I tried to import it already, and that is a no go.

Comment: I actually used this, and had it backwards. Thanks!

Comment: check @class DTContact

Answer (score 0):

Its not relevant to ur case but I was getting the same error. I googled for a solution but the problem was in my code. I was using different class object as I was copy pasting similar snippet of code in my project. So here is the problem that I had for the same error :

For my classA , I had some code snippet like :

```
    ManagedObjectOfClassA * managedObjectOfClassA = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ManagedObjectOfClassA"                                                              inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

    managedObjectOfClassA.somePropertyA = sameValue; //somePropertyA is an attribute of ManagedObjectOfClassA
```

And similar code for class B :

```
    ManagedObjectOfClassA *managedObjectOfClassB = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ManagedObjectOfClassB" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

    managedObjectOfClassB.somePropertyB = someValue;////somePropertyB is an attribute of ManagedObjectOfClassB
```

If u look closely, the mistake was in assigning the right entities to the corresponding objects in class B.

So the problem is in code of class B. And the correct code would be :

ManagedObjectOf**ClassB** *managedObjectOfClassB = [NSEntityDescription                                                               insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ManagedObjectOf**ClassB**"                                                              inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

managedObjectOf**ClassB**.**somePropertyB**.someValue;

I hope that helps someone.